# My AMD/ATI HD 7570M is overheating after install Ubuntu 12.04.2

Tags: ati, radeon

I get the last Ubuntu version to install in my Inspiron 14z, but after install it, the video card is overheating, the battery is get down too fast.

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience and the only solution for me was to use the KDE desktop instead of Unity. I tried to install the AMD video drivers directly from AMD first however all that happened for me was that it killed Unity and I saw a blank screen when I logged in.

If have found that the 12.10 version of Ubuntu is not stable on AMD machines. Even with the switch to the KDE desktop, the performance while better was nothing near the performance of my 11.x versions of Ubuntu. Lucky I still had my old instance and could revert back to it.

Give this a try and good luck.

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/legacy/Pages/legacy-radeon_linux.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will test it and see how this work, thanks so much!!!

Comment: Hi, thanks for help me about this issue, but, the drive that you told me don't work and i search for others and i found it amd-driver-installer-catalyst-12.11-beta-x86.x86_64.run.

After download it, i converted it to Debian package sh ./amd-driver-installer-catalyst-12.1-legacy-linux-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/oneiric

So, after all a use the dpkg - *.deb where the files was created.

after instalation, the desktop is crash then, i install the gnome-desktop again and the cooler is less hot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to upgrade **Ubuntu 12.04.2** to **Ubuntu 12.04.3**. As **Ubuntu 12.04.2** uses **Kernel Version 3.5**, there is some compatibility issue with **AMD** Graphics Cards. **Ubuntu 12.04.3** uses **Kernel Version 3.8** which is same as used in **Ubuntu 13.04** and best supported by any graphics card including Intel, AMD.

Next thing I recommend you to use latest **AMD** graphics driver. **AMD** is providing same set of display drivers for **Linux** as it provides for **Windows**. This is the best thing of **AMD**. **AMD Catalyst Display Driver** works great for me and smoother than ever.

- Download it from : [AMD Catalyst™ Proprietary Display Driver](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx)

  You will get a complete set of instruction how to install, attached in the package.

Hope it works for you too. Just reply if you need further assistance.